# Display ACF object field data using Elementor Custom Query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, elementor

Hello i'm working on a website using elementor pro + ACF. I have create a custom post type (CPT1) with ACF object field that take another CPT2 as values. I would like to display on my CPT1 page all CPT2 linked. How can I used Custom Query to display this? I tried to write this but still not working.

```
add_action('elementor/query/13600', function ($query) {
$query->set('post_type', ['CPT2']);
$meta_query[] = [
    'post__in' => get_field(['cpt1_field_for_cpt2']),
];
$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);});
```

Comment: There are couple things here, you don't need to pass the post type as an array in the `post_type` set. it's just `'CPT2'`, also in get_field, you are passing the field string as an array, remove the brackets `[]`, you don't need those. You may also need to use the global `$post` to pass to the the `get_field( 'cpt1_field_for_cpt2', $post->ID )`

Comment: @disinfor i tried this but have some errors 
```add_action('elementor/query/13600', function ($query) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'CPT2');
    $meta_query[] = [
        'post__in' => get_field('cpt1_field_for_cpt2', $post->ID),
    ];
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
});```

Comment: What errors? We need more info.

Comment: @disinfor i dono this but not display posts. but my variable contain the right array values $results_posts
 
```add_action('elementor/query/13600', function ($query) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'CPT1');
 $results_posts= get_field('cpt1_field_for_cpt2',$post_id,false);
    $meta_query[] = [
         'post_in' => $results_posts->ID ,
    ];
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
});```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solves with this code :

```
function my_cpt_query( $query ) {
    $myPostObjetField= get_field('cpt1_field_for_cpt2',$post_id,false);
    foreach( $myPostObjetField as $post_field_item_value ) {
            $ids[] = (int) $post_field_item_value;
    }
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'CPT2');
    $query->set( 'post__in', $ids);
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/13600', 'my_cpt_query' );
```